# How does shell eval work?

Tags: shell, eval

So I wrote a script that takes an argument. The argument denotes what kind of tests to run, either qa or dev. I have the script change a value in a properties file based on the argument, originally:

```
dev="site1.com"
qa="site2.com"

if [ $1 == "dev" ]; 
then
   sed -i "s/site=.*/site=${dev}/g" myfile.properties
else ...
```

But, I changed it to:

```
dev="site1.com"
qa="site2.com"

eval environment=\$$1
sed -i "s/site=.*/site=${environment}/g" myfile.properties
```

which now makes it so I don't need an if-else structure based on the argument.

How does it work that "eval environment = \$$1" makes it so "${environment}" will actually be "${dev}" if "dev" was the argument?

In other words, using dev as the argument (sh script.sh dev)
${environment} == ${dev} rather than ${environment} == "dev"?

Comment: What is it exactly that you're asking?

Comment: Your change doesn't obviate the need for a conditional. Now you are rewriting the file even when there is no need.

Comment: The script always rewrote the file even when there was no need. I'm just making sure that the site property is always going to be correct when the script is run, disregarding all past runs.

Comment: No, you have changed the logic. Previously, the rewrite would happen only if `$1` contained "dev"; now it happens if it contains something else (including an invalid label), too.

Comment: My bad, I didn't include all the code. I only wanted to know how the eval worked. The full script includes an initial if block to print an error message if the user doesn't use the arguments 'dev' or 'qa', thus if they did use one of those arguments, the file would get rewritten with the proper site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How does `eval` work?

The basic way that `eval` works is that the arguments are treated as a command line and the command line is re-evaluated.  Quotes are re-interpreted; I/O redirection is re-interpreted; variables are re-interpreted.

Given:

```
eval environment=\$$1
```

The first pass through creates:

```
eval environment=$dev
```

The `eval` then interprets that as

```
environment=site1.com
```

#### Problem in code originally in the question

You don't put spaces around assignments in shell, even in an `eval`.

```
dev="site1.com"
qa="site2.com"

eval environment=\$$1
sed -i "s/site=.*/site=${environment}/g" myfile.properties
```

In Bash, you'd use:

```
environment=${!1}
```

This avoids the explicit `eval`, which could be dangerous if the (ab)user typed `sh yourscript '$(rm -fr $HOME &)'` instead of `sh yourscript dev`.  If you use `eval`, you had better carefully validate what you get to evaluate.

Comment: I fixed that, my bad. That's not the point though. With the spaces fixed, I'm just trying to find out why ${environment} == ${dev} rather than ${environment} == "dev". I guess maybe how eval works in the first place.

Comment: @elrobe: see update.  Note that the caveats about using `eval` remain valid.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! That explanation makes a lot of sense.